# KineticJS: how to get all Rect/etc. and how to set a custom ID?

Tags: kineticjs

I'm using **KineticJS** and I'm adding some rectangles to the layer:

```
var kNode = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 300,
    y: 300,
    cornerRadius: 8,
    fill: '#ffffff',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    stroke: '#cccccc',
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    draggable: true
});

    kNode.customAttrs = new Object(); // attributes that I need as reference
    kNode.customAttrs.chosen = 0;
```

I need to:

- assign a **custom ID**(a GUID) to each rectangle. I tried by **kNode.id("idaa23434")** (as written in documentation: http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Rect.html ) but it tells me that the object has no method id().
- I need to get an ARRAY with all those **Rect** whose attribute **kNode.customAttrs.chosen** (which I added taking advantage that Rect is an object) is == 1. Normally I use jQuery selector **$('.node[chosen="1"]')** but since Rect are not DOM elements I can't do it.
- is there any way to get the **corresponding DOM element** to the Rect? I tried to see HTML in Chrome Developer Tools but no DOM element is displayed.

Thanks in advance for any clue.

**EDIT:**

I don't understand why by using

```
console.log(stage);
```

in **jsfiddle** I get this output (Chrome developer console):

```
Kinetic.Stage {nodeType: "Stage", children: Kinetic.Collection[1], _id: 1, eventListeners: Object, attrs: Object…}
```

but in my app I get: (the code is **the same**)

```
Kinetic.Stage {children: Kinetic.Collection[1], _id: 1, eventListeners: Object, attrs: Object, cache: Object…}
```

In fact if I use **stage.find()** on jsfiddle it works, but in my app doesn't ( **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'find' **).

Any clue? I got the same problem while working with canvas elements, since I got **prevObject**, but not the object itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In KineticJS, the id is similar to the html id:**

```
// SET

kNode.setId(123);

// GET
// 
// specify #123 to get an id
// .find returns a set so use [0] to get the first element

var id123 = stage.find("#123")[0];

id123.setFill("green");
```

**In KineticJS, the name is similar to the html class:**

```
// SET

kNode.setName("chosen1");

// GET
// specify .chosen1 to get a name

var chosen1=stage.find(".chosen1");

chosen1.each(function(i){
    i.setFill("blue");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/vnEPL/

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. It works. But I don't understand: why .setName, setId etc. are not shown in KineticJS docs (http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Rect.html) ? there are .name(), .id() etc. but they do NOT work.. >> NEVERMIND: I found them under "Shape" section

Comment: >> EDIT: I found. id() under "Shape" but not .setName() (not even with Google advanced search)

Comment: Yep, KineticJS documentation is not great.  New versions come out so fast that property and method names are often changing.  It can be frustrating! :-\  Sometimes you have to dig into the Github source code for answers.

Comment: of course I will. but before I want to figure out why .find method doesn't work (please check my updated question)

Comment: ok. I can't believe it, but I updated to laest version of Kinetics (5.0.0) and issue gone. And of course API have changed!

Answer (score 4):

You can get all the Rectangle in the stage using :

```
rects = stage.find("Rect");
rects.each(function (node) {
//do what u want
}
```

i think this will solve your problem

Comment: I tried to use .find on stage. but it says it has no method "find"